# Current futures and web scraping: implicitly wait not working correctly

Tags: python, multithreading, selenium, web-scraping, concurrent.futures

I'm trying to web scrape this page https://www.bumeran.com.pe/empleos-publicacion-menor-a-7-dias.html

I use a code to get the URLs I need to get data from. However, the usual code takes about 2 hours to run, so I want to optimize it. I read I could use multi-threading, but I'm having issues implementing it.

My simplified code is as follows:

```py
import concurrent.futures
import time
from selenium import webdriver

options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
#options.add_argument('--headless')
options.add_argument('--no-sandbox')
options.add_argument('--disable-dev-shm-usage')

PATH = "C:\Program Files (x86)\chromedriver.exe"
wd = webdriver.Chrome(PATH, options=options)
wd.maximize_window()

def info(url):
    wd.get(url)

    try:
        wd.implicitly_wait(20)
        titulo = wd.find_element_by_xpath("//h1").text
        empresa = wd.find_element_by_class_name('FichaAvisoSubHeader__Company-sc-1poii24-2.bkFDjf').text
        detalle = wd.find_element_by_class_name('FichaAviso__DescripcionAviso-sc-b2a7hd-11.kjUXkd').text
        
        print('URL completada')

    except Exception as ex:
        titulo=''
        empresa=''
        detalle=''
        template = "An exception of type {0} occurred. Arguments:\n{1!r}"
        message = template.format(type(ex).__name__, ex.args)
        print(message)

    vtitulo.append(titulo)
    vempr.append(empresa)
    vdetalle.append(detalle)

vtitulo = []
vempr = []
vdetalle = []
vurl = ['https://www.bumeran.com.pe/empleos/asistente-contable-exp.-en-concar-ssp-1114585777.html',
 'https://www.bumeran.com.pe/empleos/asesor-a-comercial-digital-de-seguro-vehicular-1114584904.html',
 'https://www.bumeran.com.pe/empleos/mecanico-de-mantenimiento-arequipa-1114585709.html',
 'https://www.bumeran.com.pe/empleos/almacenero-l.o.-electronics-s.a.c.-1114585629.html',
 'https://www.bumeran.com.pe/empleos/analista-de-comunicaciones-ingles-avanzado-teleperformance-peru-s.a.c.-1114564863.html',
 'https://www.bumeran.com.pe/empleos/vendedores-adn-retail-s.a.c.-1114585422.html',
 'https://www.bumeran.com.pe/empleos/especialista-de-intervencion-de-proyectos-mondelez-international-1114585461.html',
 'https://www.bumeran.com.pe/empleos/desarrollador-java-senior-inetum-peru-1114584840.html',
 'https://www.bumeran.com.pe/empleos/practicante-legal-coes-sinac-1114584788.html',
 'https://www.bumeran.com.pe/empleos/concurso-publico-n-143-especialista-en-presupuesto-banco-central-de-reserva-del-peru-1114584538.html']


start_time = time.time()

with concurrent.futures.ThreadPoolExecutor(max_workers=4) as executor:
    executor.map(info, vurl)

print("--- %i seconds ---" % (time.time() - start_time))
```

In some URLs, the result sends me to the StaleElementReferenceException, so I think my problem is that it's running too fast that the page doesn't finish loading. I've tried to introduce waits but that doesn't seem to work. Also, I don't know if I'm correctly using the Threading. I thought that it would open 4 Chrome browsers, but it doesn't seem to do so.

Any help is welcomed :)

Thanks in advance and sorry if it's a dumb question

Comment: Put `wd.implicitly_wait(20)` before `wd.get(url)`.

Comment: that sends me to the exception in all URLs :(

Comment: Put it before `info(url)` is called. In case of persistence there is another cause of the exception.